# ID variable in cPanel email forward

Tags: email, cpanel, postmark, email-forwarding

I am building an app that incorporates Postmark App's Incoming Email capability to keep a threaded list of replies to an email. Their documentation suggests adding the post ID to the reply-to address - for example `reply+POSTID@domain.com`. However, when I attempt to use this method with cPanel, the emails are bounced back.

I have `reply@domain.com` set up, without adding the post ID the email is forwarded to the Postmark App inbox address, adding the ID breaks it. Is there any way to do this in a WHM/cPanel environment? It is a VPS account so I have full access if there is another way to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the messages bounced back from Postmark or is it a cpanel error? I can probably help you out there! Do you have an MX record setup for Inbound via http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-inbound-mx.html ? Once you have that going Postmark will accept messages from any address on that domain and parse off the addresses with + chars in them. Are we sure cpanel can handle email addresses with special characters?